# What can a power set of a countable infinite set contain?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, infinity

So I was wondering if this is complete power set of the power set of natural numbers.

1. All sets of any finite combinations of natural numbers that can exist. For example, {1, 2, 4}, {4, 2, 5, 6, 7}, {1000, 1 , 78} etc.
2. An empty set(Φ) and the set containing all natural numbers(N).
3. All sets which contain all natural numbers except a particular finite set of natural numbers. For example N - {1, 2, 4}, N -  {4, 2, 5, 6, 7}, N - {1000, 1 , 78} etc.

This is all I was able to think of. I feel like I am definitely missing something here.

Comment: What about the even numbers, for instance?

Comment: Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Answer (score 5):

You've missed the **bi-infinite** sets - sets which are infinite and have infinite complement. For example, the set of *even numbers* is not on your list; neither is the set of prime numbers, the set of perfect cubes, or so on.

In fact, **most sets of natural numbers are bi-infinite** in the precise sense that the set of non-bi-infinite sets of naturals is [*countable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set) but the set of bi-infinite sets of naturals is [*uncountable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_set). The first of these claims is a good exercise; the second is [Cantor's diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument).

Comment: So a set containing all the elements that I have mentioned will be a countable set?

Comment: @CalmMango Yes. It may help to first prove that the set of *finite* sets is countable, and then show that the set of *finite or cofinite* (= finite complement) sets is countable. Note that $\emptyset$ is finite and $\mathbb{N}$ is cofinite, so they don't have to be listed separately.

Comment: (Incidentally, "cofinite" is a bit of a loaded term - in order for it to make sense we need to presuppose a "universal set" we're living in. Here that set is $\mathbb{N}$, but this can vary; for example, the set of natural numbers $>4$ is cofinite as a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ but bi-infinite as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.)